# Как правильно очистить ссылку перед записью в бд?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

У пользователя есть возможность добавить ссылку, ссылка записывается в базу данных.
Как правильно очистить эту ссылку перед записью в бд ?

Comment: воспользуйтесь функцией php `urlencode()`

Comment: Уточните — очистить от чего? Если речь об sql-иньекции, то такая «очистка» происходит на уровне формирования sql-запроса для любых текстов, а не только ссылок.